# How to pass a JSON object in OkHttp RequestBody for calling external APIs

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

```
@Test
public void whenSendPostRequest_thenCorrect() 
 throws IOException {
    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("username", "test")
        .add("password", "test")
        .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(BASE_URL + "/users")
        .post(formBody)
        .build();
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    Response response = call.execute();
    
    assertThat(response.code(), equalTo(200));
}
```

Reference - https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-okhttp

I am trying to execute this type of request where while forming `formBody` I have to do something like this  to have  `.add("something", json_object)` but it accepts a string value and I can't pass JSON string how to solve this issue.

Also `json_object` is very large so can't just have many `.add` statements for each key value pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some exploration I found out that we can convert json_string to requestbody json using okhttp Requestbody class create method which takes json mediatype and json_string as parameter and then this body can be passes to .post method of the request builder.

```
MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to create a model/pojo class which has the fields same as that in the json string. Then have an object of that class type added to the FormBody class. You can have a json to object mapper to convert the input json to an object of new model class.

Comment: Yes prasanth, I have a model class which i am converting to json string using object mapper but this formBody .add parameter only accepts string arguements both key and value

Comment: Ok Dhruv got your point, once you have the object ready we can make use of jackson library to convert that object to string format. 

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter; 

ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(object);

formBody.add("keyName", json);

Comment: Another way to achieve this with ObjectMapper - (not tested, you may test and use as per your need !)

`code` Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.firstName = "Test";
emp.lastName = "Emp";
emp.email = "testemp@test.com";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
try {
    // convert user object to json string and return it 
    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(u);
}
catch (JsonParsingException  e) {
    // catch various errors
    e.printStackTrace();
}
`code`
jsonString would look like this {"firstName":"Test","lastName":"Emp","email":"testemp@test.com"}

Answer (score 0):

So you need the Integration test here. I am using something like this:

```
TestDto testDto = new TestDto(); //  you need to set the field variables here

given()
    .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, createJwtToken(ADMIN_ID))
    .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, LANG_EN)
    .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
    .body(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testDto))
    .when()
        .log().all()
        .post(CONTROLLER_ENDPOINT)
    .then()
        .log().all()
        .statusCode(HttpStatus.CREATED.value())
    .extract()
        .body().as(TestDto.class);
```

given() will be found in [rest-assured](https://rest-assured.io/).

[ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) is a class that can be found in a jackson library: jackson-databind. createJwtToken() is responsible to give a JWT with the ADADMIN_ID.

Hope, it will help.